# How can i write a vba code to determine if text matches parametres?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a VBA function which checks the following:

1. if the text is atleast 6 characters long;
2. if the first 2 letters are capital;
3. and the last 3 symbols are numbers.

Answer has to be "true" or "false"

I don't even know where to begin so i'd appreciate anything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can be done without vba: AND(LEN(A1)>=6,LEFT(A1,2)=UPPER(LEFT(A1,2)),ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,3)*1)) So, this is to show that vba is not needed: So LEN() checks for 6 or more, LEFT() of the first 2 characters is compared to the result of upper() to make sure the first two are uppercase, isnumber() makes sure the last 3 are numerical.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done without vba:

```
AND(LEN(A1)>=6,LEFT(A1,2)=UPPER(LEFT(A1,2)),ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,3)*1))
```

[image]

So LEN() checks for 6 or more,
LEFT() of the first 2 characters is compared to the result of upper() to make sure the first two are uppercase,
ISNUMBER() makes sure the last 3 are numerical.

Answer (score 1):

The below VBA function will do what you ask for.

```
Function Check_Text(InputText As String) As Boolean
Check_Text = (Len(InputText) >= 6 And InputText Like "[A-Z][A-Z]*###")
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, I did not realize `Like` was so powerful! I just stress tested this and it works beautifully! -> Does the `[A-Z]` work like an alphanumeric range definition? For example could I `[A-C]` to get A, B, C? Could I do `[5-9]` to filter number ranges? Would `[a-z]` give my lowercase, and would `[A-z]` give me both lcase and ucase?

Comment: Are there any other ways to define `Like` parameters aside from `[X-Y]`, `*` and `#`?

Comment: Also, @Ramon Saluveer, mark this one correct, because It's the easiest and simplest possible form of what you requested.

Comment: @cameron yes, `Like` is a very powerful text comparison operator - just Google "VBA like operator" for full details but in brief your guesses are correct - `[square brackets]` allow any character in a range, `#` is any numeric character, `?` is any letter, and `*` is for any or no characters

Comment: @cameron I believe it only works on text strings though, so " using [5-9] to filter number ranges" would work if the digit is stored as a string, but wouldnt work on a Long or Integer variable.